# Trying to get inner text from GWT Label

Tags: java, gwt

I have defined a label with Java GWT.

```
Label a = new Label();
```

And assigned a value from a List called resultlist:

```
a.setText(resultlist.get(1));
```

Now, i want to get access to what's inside the label. The label itself it is inside a Html Layout Container. To access the label I have the following code line which is inside a click event:

```
Label label = (Label) event.getSource();
```

"label", contains the following :

```
 <div class="btext" style="width: 250px; cursor: pointer;">BASIC Feb 2014</div>
```

And i want to get access to "BASIC Feb 2014", capture it and store it into a variable for later use.

Anyone can enlighten me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be as simple as `label.getText()` ?

Comment: Ok, dumb question i made, Sorry for wasting your time. I will take your response as the accepted one. Thank you :).